# finish an activity which is not on the top of activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, destroy

I have three activity A, B and C, C being on top of the activity stack. C contains fragments, f1, f2. On click of a button I want to replace "f1" with "f2" and finish activity A, B.  Any thoughts how this can accomplished.

Comment: See my answer. When on click launch Activity D and add f2 fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` when you start the Activity D. This will clear the all Activity in stack, but including Activity C in your case.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

It will clear all the Activity in stack.

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. i.e., the activity becomes the new root and any old activities are finished. This flag can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0):

How about this, first

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Removes other Activities from stack
    //Add Intent Extra to Start Activity C
    intent.putExtra("startC", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Add an extra to the intent, then get the intent in the Activity A
if that extra comes back true start Activity C with intent extra, and

```
    finish(); //Activity A.

    intent.putExtra("startD", true);
```

Grab that intent to start Activity D, then C will be on the stack under D

What I am suggesting is Clearing the stack by going to Activity A, getting any intent to start specified activity, then intent stacking to where you need to go, hope this makes sense.

If you are looking to have only Activity D be on top, use this

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // Removes other Activities from stack
        //Start Activity 
        startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna say using the `intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` but it will just gonna clear all the activity on the top of it..

I will suggest to create a static method or maybe handler.. having a finish method on them so you can freely finish an activity anyone you want by calling them without finishing all the activity.

create a static handler to each of your activity A ,B ,C ,D:

```
public static Handler h;

h = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch(msg.what) {

            case 0:
                finish();

    }

};
```

In your button onlick listener:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(layout, fragment, tag).commit();

ACTIVITY_A.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
ACTIVITY_B.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

eachtime you call the handler it will finish the activity A and B also replacing the fragment

Comment: Thanks!! Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears all the activities in the stack, I want to clear the activities on a "particular event", I want all the activities to be in the stack till "particular event" is triggered. I don't think CLEAR_TOP won't be complete my purpose.

Comment: Thanks!! What you said makes sense, unfortunately am using fragments and am not launching any new activities, but rather replacing the "previous fragment" just before executing this event I have to clear my activity stack as well.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Thanks to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flags

Comment: Do you see any issue in accepting my answer ? . It might help others

Comment: I don't know how to accept an answer :(. Didn't find any button or link to do so. Let me know how to do that.

Comment: You could see an tick mark left to my Answer below .

Comment: Answer Accepted !! smiles :